# Decrypting data with Rsa Private Key/Function

Tags: encryption, cryptography, byte, rsa, crypto++

I'm just trying to encode/decode data (decode, firstly)  with RSA.
I don't care of the type of data (string, bytes, or other lolcat-encoded data), I just looking a very simple function doing the job (cryptographic operations) and I can do the rest.

Here is what I tried :

```cpp
CryptoPP::InvertibleRSAFunction rsa;

rsa.SetModulus( n_factor );
rsa.SetPrivateExponent(d_private_exponent);

rsa.SetPrime1( rsa_params.at(p1) );
rsa.SetPrime2( rsa_params.at(p2) );

// All above inputs are correct. I don't have public exponent, but it's works in other languages (I comprared all inputs/outputs)

bool key_ok = rsa.Validate(CryptoPP::NullRNG(), 15);
/* Returns false, but doesn't tell me why :/ */

CryptoPP::Integer to_decode( my_data, size_of_my_data );
res = rsa.CalculateInverse(rg,to_decode);
```

This returns:

```
EXCEPTION : what():  CryptoMaterial: this object contains invalid values
```

Returned error code corresponds to `"INVALID_DATA_FORMAT"`, which probably doesn't mean a key problem, but an input problem.

If anyone has some experience with this library, or detects a "noob" mistake (I've my mind in code since 4 hours, so it is possible), any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "`bool key_ok = rsa.Validate(CryptoPP::NullRNG(), 15)`" - I'm not sure this is right. I think you need a real PRNG, and not the `NullRNG`. That's because some of the tests are probabilistic. Also, the highest level you can use is 3, not 15. See [Keys and Formats, Validating Keys](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Keys_and_Formats#Validating_Keys).

Comment: Also see [Raw RSA](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Raw_RSA) on the Crypto++ wiki. Its not advised, though.

Answer (score 1):

Easier than I thought :

```
CryptoPP::Integer dec_data = a_exp_b_mod_c( enc_data, d_private_exponent, n_modulus );
```

So 'd' and 'n' were enought. I really don't understand why it didn't work with crypto features.

Comment: `a_exp_b_mod_c` performs an exponentiation, but does *not* apply padding. That means a small exponent could leak information; and if the same message is encrypted twice, then the attacker will learn it. Its probably better to use a higher level object and OAEP padding.